# SQL database averaging a value for distinct people

Tags: sql, average

[image]

I would like to average the weights which can be seen in the picture. 
That means the calculation I want to make is : (50+65+70+68+70)/5
Do you know how to do that? (to specifically select the weights ones for every person using the household number and person number)

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Also: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557

Comment: Your image shows six records and your calculation only takes five into account. By what rule do you determine which records to calculate the avarage for?

Comment: Is it your second question: [postgresql averaging weights](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36891802/postgresql-averaging-weights)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seem you want to average  the distinct weights per household:

```
SELECT AVG(Weight)
FROM
 (
   SELECT DISTINCT HouseHoldNumber, Weight -- maybe need to add TravelNumber or PersonNumber
   FROM tab
 ) AS dt
```

Answer (score 1):

Average weights per person.....
Your initial question misleads into thinking you want the average for all.

```
SELECT HouseHoldNumber, PersonNumber, AVG(Weight) as AVG_Weight
FROM YOUR_TABLE
GROUP BY
  HouseHoldNumber, PersonNumber
```

Simply add a WHERE if you want top do it for a specific house & Person.

Answer (score 0):

Use "Select AVG(your_column) From your_table"

Comment: No it selects than the weight of the person number 2 of the household number 2 twice since it is mentioned in two lines.

Comment: So I think "Select avg(weight) From your_table Where weight in (select distinct household, person, weight From your_table" is good

Answer (score 0):

uh

```
select avg(weight) from table
```

Comment: No it selects than the weight of the person number 2 of the household number 2 twice since it is mentioned in two lines

Comment: And just how are we supposed to know that is the same person?

Answer (score 0):

This will give you the average per household, per person.

```
SELECT [Household Number], [Person Number], AVG(Weight)
FROM Your_Table
GROUP BY [Household Number], [Person Number]
```